# How to optimize is List have an element check? C#

Tags: c#, arrays, list

Hi I have a few lines of code that checks if the element is in `List`

But when List becomes too bigit consumes too much RAM is ther any whay to imrove it so it consumese lesser RAM

```
List<string> list = File.ReadAllLines(path);
string user = dynamic;
if (list.Contains(user))
{
    return "go";
}
else
{
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Yes. Use Stream to read file. And your question is related to _file reading_ to memory not a List itself.

Comment: how about not reading all the lines at ones ? Have a look at `ReadLines` method.

Comment: Need more information about the usecase here, is it a one-off check for 1 user type of thing, or do you check for many users against the same file, or ...? If it's a one-off thing you can do `File.ReadLines(path).Any(line => line == user)`.

Comment: What is consuming the RAM? The list itself? Or are you saying the search is time consuming?